# fill object's empty values with anything

Tags: javascript, node.js

As a beginner still in JS, I have to crack someone else's code that is not documented, obviously.

At some point this code arrives to the function that is supposed to build an object.

```
let obj = {
catName:"cat",
catAge: someAge,
catLength: "one half of a meter no one cares how many cm",
...
}
```

This object is then sent to another function that is assigning keys to the table names to print out this object in .csv format against column names (to be able to open it in Excel for example)

The datamodel is saved in a separate JS file.

function that would parse to csv format uses this:

```
    const pathtoFile = `////directories/cat.csv`;
  
    const globalParser = new Parser({
      header: !fs.existsSync(pathtoFile),
      delimiter: ";",
      excelStrings: false,
      fields: ReportFields,   //here is where the object data model comes from
    });

    const data = globalParser.parse(**catOBJ**) + "\n"; //catObj here is exactly what arrives and what is to be parsed

    if (!fs.existsSync(pathtoFile)) {
      fs.mkdirpSync(tmpcatReportsPath);
      fs.writeFileSync(pathtoFile, data, "utf-8");
    } else {
      fs.appendFileSync(pathtoFile, data, "utf-8");
    }
```

Problem:
I need to make sure that even if I do not know some of the values for some keys( ex: catLength), I can still assure that the object will get to .csv format and instead of this column name I will simply have ""

Questions:

1. Does it look more reasonable to you that I first fetch this template object , create an instance of it and then assign the parameters I know to it and then send it to the function?
2. if not, how do you proceed to make sure that the values that are not known are positioned as "" if I do not have a clue what these key-names are?

Comment: Do you have a list of the column keys? How do you generate the CSV?

Comment: With what value do you want to fill?

Comment: @AlexandroPalacios as I mentioned I want it just to be empty. ""

Comment: @epascarello , I will update the question with the info about the csv parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do you proceed to make sure that the values that are not known are positioned as "" if I do not have a clue what these key-names are?

**1)** To obtain the keys of an object you should ouse the `Object.keys()` function, which returns an array with keys like `['catName', 'catAge', 'catLength', ...]`.

**2)** Once you have the keys of the object, you should map each of them and check if there is a `null` value:

```
let keys = Object.keys(obj);    // Get array of keys

let result = {};

// Iterate all keys
keys.forEach(key => {
    result[key] = (obj[key] == null ? "" : obj[key]);
});
```

- Notice that using `obj[key] == null` will also catch `undefined` values.

**You can try the code in the snippet:**

```js
let obj = {
  catName: "cat",
  catAge: 5,
  catLength: "one half of a meter no one cares how many cm",
  catColor: null   // Need to catch this
};

let keys = Object.keys(obj);

let result = {};

keys.forEach(key => {
  result[key] = (obj[key] == null ? "" : obj[key]);
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: the fact that it will also catch the undefined values is brilliant thank you so much